# Div sizes not matching and auto height issues

Tags: html, css

Working on site for a school project running into silly issues.

http://jmtestserver.net46.net/

1)  So first thing I'm wondering, my height on the div with the textured background is set at a manual PX.  I want this to be set at auto because I'm making this responsive so I want it to grow and shrink with the box divs.  However, if I set it to auto it looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kBtd.png

I don't understand why the box divs arent pushing it down??

2)  As you can see the 2 boxes on the right stick down further than the 2 boxes on the left.  I don't understand why this is because the boxes use the exact same css other than color and the image sizes are are exactly the same.  So I cant figure out for the life of me why they wont match up heightwise.

Thank you in advance!  I know these are simple things but they are causing me a lot of trouble!

Comment: Could you plz add fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The problem with your footer "floating" up behind your boxes has to do with the "float: left;" on your boxes. The elements after your boxes will basically ignore the boxes as if they werent there. To fix this simply add clear: both; to a element after the float happens.

You can read more about it here: [Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

```
#bottom-section {
    clear: both;
}
```

2) The boxes being bigger has to do with your images not being the same size, either find/make images with the same height or add a height value to .photo_icon

```
.photo_icon {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The clear stopped that problem but the background texture is still not appearing right, see: http://i.imgur.com/3MZ8jMz.png.   EDIT: adding a float onto the content section seemed to have fixed that

Comment: Aah i totally missed that. Instead of using float you could use display: inline-block; on #content

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your webpage you will see that the images are not all the same size. You can force them to be by changing your `main.css`. Modify `.photo_icon` as below:

```
.photo_icon {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    height: 99px; /* This line */
}
```

Comment: How are you guys seeing the size of the image? It's my first time working with SVG but in illustrator they all appear to be the same size.  I even brought the other icons in and lined them up on the ones that are working and did a save as so I don't understand why theyd be bigger

Comment: Like here is a gfy of how I am trying to match the size - http://gfycat.com/ChillyFlawlessDrever

Comment: @user4340635 use the developer tools in the browser (right click and choose something like `inspect element`)

Comment: ah ok I see that.  I wish there was a way I could check the actual files because I dont see how they could be different size the way I am making them.

Answer (score 1):

1. question: icons in 3rd and 4th box are bigger (height 98px vs. 55px in first two cases).
2. question: boxes has content of different height and take exactly the same height as its content. As I said, content in 3rd and 4th box is higher than in first two boxes.

**Solution:**
resize/crop your icons to the same size (height). If you add `.photo_icon {height: 55px;}` you'll see it will work correctly with icons with proper size.

Comment: Here is a GFY if me trying to resize and they KEEP coming out like that it makes no sense to me... http://gfycat.com/ChillyFlawlessDrever

Answer (score 1):

Heights of your images are not same. If you make them same size, or add something like

height: 101px;

to your .photo_icon class, it would solve the problem